# Convexity of non-compact, ball-connected sets

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, convex-geometry

At one of my lectures recently (https://github.com/joanbruna/MathsDL-spring18/blob/master/lectures/lecture13.pdf , on the slide titled Parametric vs Manifold Optimization), I came across the definition of ball-connected set:

A set is ball-connected if its intersection with balls of any radius and is a single connected component.

I remember it being said that this definition is weaker than convexity. What I don't understand is that how is this any different from convexity? Can't we just make the radius $r$ large enough that the intersection with this set is just a hyperplane cutting the set, and if its still connected for every such hyperplane then it is convex, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider unit ball with its centre removed then it's not convex.

But it's ball-connected as it's intersection with any radius ball is single connected set.

For example, consider open unit disk in $\mathbb R^2$.

Hence ball-connected is weaker notion than convexity.

Comment: Thanks! The example clears everything up! :)

Comment: Will do soon! You have to wait 15 minutes after posting a question to accept an answer on this site.

Comment: A circle is ball connected but an ellispe is not.  Weird.  What is this answer accept thing?  Another secret feature of math stack?